# Safely convert an 'any' object to an object that conforms to a TypeScript interface

Tags: json, typescript

I would like the proper way to convert an object of type `any` to an object that conforms to a particular interface, say `ApiResponse` with proper error handling if it doesn't have the necessary properties for it to become that object. The object of type `any` came from a JSON payload, from a JSON.parse or equivalent. I would ideally like some proper error handling dealing with this conversion, as well. I have come up with the following approach, but not sure if it's using TypeScript properly or exploiting the best patterns.

Answer (score -1):

```
`

export interface ApiResponse {

    code: number 
    type: string 
    message: string 

}



export function readApiResponse(json: any): ApiResponse {

    if (!json.hasOwnProperty('code')) {
        throw 'No code property'
    }

    if (!json.hasOwnProperty('type')) {
        throw 'No type property'
    }

    if (!json.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
        throw 'No message property'
    }

    return json
}


loadData() {
        fetch("data.json")
            .then(response => response.json()) 
            .then( (json: any) => {

                console.log(json)

                let r = readApiResponse(json)

                console.log(r)

                this.setState( {message : r.message })

            })
            .catch ( (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })

    }
```

`

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure why this question and approach was down-voted. This is particular to ensuring an object produced from JSON has the proper properties defined in order to conform to the interface. I suppose since at runtime, after transpilation, the notion of an interface is no longer used.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but it is not clear to me how this will scale to realistically sized APIs with nested types, optional values, values with other restrictions on them. Also it doesn't error if the response has extra fields... (though its not clear to me that it should...)

Comment: Oh and it doesn't actually error if the types aren't as expected. So `{code:"foo", type:11, message:[]}` will get through your `readApiResponse` just fine.